# Password is not checking case sensitivity

Tags: php, mysql

I have a login form in a website which I have created.I have used PHP for verifying password,and password is stored in MYSQL database.The problem i'm facing is Password is not case sensitive.It accepts the characters without considering the case.I'm using Kubuntu linux OS

Could anyone please help to solve this problem?.What value I should use for COLLATION in mysql/my.cnf to avoid this?Or is there any other solution for this?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: For better password protection, don't store them into the database, hash them first. use the PHP function `md5()` or even better `sha1()`. A given password is always hashed the same way. When you want to check if the password is correct, hash the entered one and compare the hashes. Hashing **is** case sensitive.

Comment: [You are doing it wrong](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/09/youre-probably-storing-passwords-incorrectly.html)

Comment: Thanks for giving me the idea for storing the password using md5 or sha1.

Comment: @user725719: don't invent something yourself though - read up on how it's supposed to work, and implement that. If you have question, please, ask them!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your MySQL **collation is probably case-insensitive**. Change the column where the password is stored to a case-sensitive collation.

Some rules of thumb:

- When a collation ends in _ci, it is case-insensitive.
- When a collation ends in _cs, it is case-sensitive.

Example:

- utf8_general_ci is case-insensitive.
- utf8_bin is case-sensitive

#### However, an important note

If you are experiencing this problem, you are **probably storing the passwords wrong**. You should not store the passwords in plain text, but you should store a hash of the password instead, and salt it properly.

Then, when a user logs in, you hash his entry, and compare the hash with what your DB holds. When both equal, the user probably entered a correct password.

Answer (score 1):

This implies that you're storing the passwords in plaintext which is usually not a good idea.  Anyway, one option would be to retrieve the password and compare it in PHP instead of in a WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

One other way to solve your problem would be to hash the password before storing it into the database. This would also increase the security as the password would not be stored unencrypted in the database.

```
$hash_to_store_in_database = sha1($password);
```

You can search on the web for how to store hashed passwords, using salt and all other security things.

Answer (score 1):

While Konerak's answer is correct, I would go a different way and not store the password in clear, but a hash, possibly an `md5` or `sha1`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are storing password in general text. Otherwise collation like `utf8_general_ci` should not be a problem generally.

You should hash you password with md5() or sha1() while you store passwords.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *strcmp* function in php or use something like

```
"SELECT [...] WHERE BINARY tablename.password = $form_password"
```