# How do I write a case sensitive query in ColdFusion? I want user name and password to be case sensitive

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

How do I write a case sensitive query in ColdFusion?  I want user name and password to be case sensitive. This is what I have:

```
<cfquery datasource="myDataSource" name="qVerify">
    SELECT *
      FROM tblUsers
     WHERE userName = '#userName#' 
       AND password = '#password#'
</cfquery>
<cfif qVerify.RecordCount>
    <cfset session.allowin = "True" />
    <cfset session.ID = qVerify.ID />
    { "login" : "valid" }
<cfelse>
    { "login" : "invalid" }
</cfif>
```

so if the user Dave (as it is in the database) signs in as dave it will not be valid...

Comment: you should not be storing a password in plain text, hashing the password would remove this issue

Comment: Agreed. That said, always include your DBMS and version in any query questions. Frequently, the answer is database dependent. You will get a faster, more accurate, answer if you include your db type and version in the tags.

Comment: Bear in mind, Jc3Web, that CF simply passes the SQL statement to the DB server, so this is not really a CF question, but one dpecific to your DB server platform (eg: SQL Sever, Oracle etc). So in that light, it's vital you tag your question with that info.

Comment: It's only been said twice, so I'll say it again: > > > ***DO NOT STORE PASSWORDS IN PLAINTEXT!*** < < <   Use a [KDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) to produces an iterated salted hash of the value. (Also, use [cfqueryparam](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfqueryparam) instead of directly including variables, and avoid writing `SELECT *` - list the columns you need.)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, some things I'm still new too. I'm using MySQL 5. Not exactly sure how to properly set up using a password. Also, on the select * I've read a lot of comments saying list the columns, this still hold true even if there are 3 or 4 columns and you want them all anyway?

Comment: @Jc3web - Do a search on ColdFusion hashed passwords. There are tons of examples out there. The gist is 1) store the *hashed* password in the database, 2) then compare the hashed value in your `where` clause instead of the plain text value. That way you never store or transmit the password in plain text. Note, there are different algorithms, so read up on the differences. If you run into problems, or have further questions, just open a new question.

Answer (score 2):

This should treat the columns as case-sensitive, but you should really fix the issue of your passwords being stored as plain text.

```
<!--- MS SQL Server ---> 
<cfquery datasource="myDataSource" name="qVerify">
SELECT *
FROM tblUsers
WHERE userName = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#userName#"> COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_A
AND password = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#password#"> COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_A
</cfquery>
```

---

**(Update from comments)**

The exact collation names are database dependent. For MySQL:

```
<!--- MySQL ---> 
<cfquery datasource="myDataSource" name="qVerify">
SELECT *
FROM tblUsers
WHERE userName = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#userName#"> COLLATE latin1_general_cs
AND password = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#password#"> COLLATE latin1_general_cs
</cfquery>
```

See the [documentation on charset/collate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-mysql.html) for more details.

Comment: Psst... `cfqueryparam` :)

Comment: Thanks. Not sure the best way for dealing with passwords to not store them as plain text, I'm using MySQL 5, any tips?

Comment: When trying the code you provided I get:  Error Executing Database Query. Unknown collation: 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_A'

Comment: (Edit) Collation names are db dependent. That example is for MS SQL Server. For MySQL, see the [charset/collate docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-mysql.html). Also, [check the SO archives](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[mysql]+case+sensitive). Here is [one example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10085098/password-is-not-checking-case-sensitivity).

Comment: @Matt - I updated the answer with the final version from the comments, so it is more visible. (Hope you do not mind)

Comment: @leigh don't mind at all, but the answer is basically all yours now :)

Comment: @MattBusche - Nah, it was a minor correction to the syntax. In cases like this, there is no point having two answers that say (essentially) the same thing ;-) Better to update the existing one so the solution is one place and is easy to find.

Answer (score 1):

Cast the field in the query to a case-sensitive type or to use a case-sensitive encoding.